# How to put scrollpan pointing to bottom in a modal

Tags: html, css

I was building a chat application.I have been trying to put the scroll pan in a modal always pointing to bottom unless i scroll up, but couldn't do it.The list elements are coming through ajax.can anybody help me with this.?

```
    <div class="modal-body" style="max-height: calc(50vh - 100px);
overflow-y: auto;">
    <ul class="list-group">
    </ul>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a variable to decide if scroll to bottom whenever got a message.

Here is an simplified example.

See if this is what you are looking for.

```js
var stick_bottom = true;

var t = setInterval(function() {
  got_new_message();
}, 1000);

$('.messages-container').on('scroll', function() {
  stick_bottom = ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() >= $('ul.message-list').height());
});

function got_new_message() {
  var newDate = new Date();
  $('ul.message-list').append('<li class="message">This is a new message. ('+Date.now()+')</li>');
  if (stick_bottom) {
    $('.messages-container').scrollTop($('ul.message-list').height());
  }
}
```

```css
.messages-container {
  height: 140px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #eee;
}
ul.message-list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul.message-list li.message {
  padding: 5px 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="messages-container">
  <ul class="message-list">
    <li class="message">Hello there!</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery [**`.scrollTop`**](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/#scrollTop) method.

Check sample snippet below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".modal-body").scrollTop(100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body" style="max-height: calc(50vh - 100px);
overflow-y: auto;">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```